# How can I apply MVVM and Commands in this specific WPF situation?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, routed-commands

I am having trouble with the MVVM pattern and Commands in my WPF app. The problem is not so much the MVVM pattern, but more the stuff that is going on on my GUI. I'll explain the situation:

My app can DoStuff to some files. I have a class with a function `DoStuff(int limit)`. My user user interface has the following items:

- A `Button` `DoStuffBtn` to start parsing.
- A `TextBox` `LimitTxt` to fill in a limit.
- A `CheckBox` `LimitChk` to enabled or disable the limit.

When you would "uncheck" `LimitChk`, then `LimitTxt.Text = ""` and `LimitTxt.IsEnabled = false`. When you would "check" `LimitChk`, then `LimitTxt.IsEnabled = false` again, but the text remains empty until you fill something in.

I have read many tutorials on Commands in WPF and MVVM but I just can't seem to pour my case into that mold. The example I gave is actually just a small part of my UI, but I can't seem to do this nicely either.

I keep running into questions like:

- Do I need two `Commands` for `LimitChk` (enable and disable) or just one (toggle)?
- If I bind an `int` to `LimitTxt`, what happens if I make it empty and disable it?
- Is it a clean way to just use `DoStuff(Int32.Parse(LimitTxt.Text))` when `DoStuffBtn` is pressed?
- If I use two commands on `LimitChk`, what happens with the `CanExecute()` function of `ICommand` that determines whether `LimitChk` is enabled?

So the main question is: How would the situation I described fit into a nice pattern using Commands in WPF?

Some links on WPF, Commands and MVVM i've looked at:

- http://www.devx.com/DevX/Article/37893/0/page/1
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc785480.aspx?pr=blog
- http://jmorrill.hjtcentral.com/Home/tabid/428/EntryId/432/MVVM-for-Tarded-Folks-Like-Me-or-MVVM-and-What-it-Means-to-Me.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

---

What I understand so far is that I have to keep as much as possible out of the UI. Even stuff like UI influencing the UI. I.e. unchecking `LimitChk` disables `LimitText`. Still, I think I should keep a difference between UI related information and actions and stuff that actually has to do with the actual work that has to be done.

Comment: lol at jmorrill's tarded folks like me post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just some high level thoughts, leaving out superfluous stuff like Color and alignment attributes, WrapPanels, etc.

Your ViewModel has a a couple properties:

```
public bool? LimitIsChecked { get; set; }
public bool LimitTextIsEnabled { get; set; }  //to be expanded, below
public ICommand ParseCommand { get; private set; } // to be expanded, below
public string LimitValue { get; set; } // further explanation, below
```

Your XAML has CheckBox and TextBox definitions something like:

```
<CheckBox Content="Limit Enabled" IsChecked="{Binding LimitIsChecked}" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding LimitValue}" IsEnabled="{Binding LimitIsEnabled}" />
<Button Content="Parse" Command="{Binding ParseCommand}" />
```

You'll want to initialize ParseCommand something like this:

```
this.ParseCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(parseFile);
```

Now, let's fill in that LimitTextIsEnabled property too:

```
public bool LimitTextIsEnabled {
    // Explicit comparison because CheckBox.IsChecked is nullable.
    get { return this.LimitIsChecked == true; }
    private set { }
}
```

Your `parseFile` method would then pass the value of the `LimitValue` property to the logic doing the actual parsing.

I declared the `LimitValue` property as string here to avoid cluttering up the code with an explicit converter, or other validation code.  You could choose to handle that "LimitValue is a valid int" verification/conversion in several different ways.

Of course, I haven't implemented this in its entirety, but I wanted to outline a pattern where you are not using Commands to update the state of the other widgets.  Instead, bind those attributes to properties that are managed in your ViewModel.

Comment: Hmm interesting solution. So if I understand correctly, the stuff on the UI that influences other stuff on the UI (i.e. the state of the checkbox influencing the state of the textbox) should go through the viewmodel. I'll have to look into what that DelegateCommand<object> thing is though. Oh and, why does the LimitTextIsEnabled property need a private set? Thanks

Comment: Yep, you have the general idea there.

LimitTextIsEnabled doesn't *need* a private set, but it doesn't need a public set either. :)

`DelegateCommand<T>` came from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc707894.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I think you're getting confused... you don't need any commands here, you can just use bindings.

> - Do I need two Commands for LimitChk (enable and disable) or just one (toggle)?

You need none. Just create a `LimitEnabled` property in your ViewModel, and bind the `CheckBox` to it (`IsChecked="{Binding LimitEnabled}"`)

> - If I bind an int to LimitTxt, what happens if I make it empty and disable it?

Disabling it has no effect. If you make the `TextBox` empty, the binding will fail because an empty string can't be converted to an int (at least not with the default converter)

> - Is it a clean way to just use Parse(Int32.Parse(LimitTxt.Text)) when ParseBtn is pressed?

You don't need to. Just create a `Limit` property in your ViewModel, and bind the `TextBox` to it. You might want to add an `ExceptionValidationRule` to the `Binding` so that it highlights invalid input.

The button is not necessary, the parsing will be done automatically when the `TextBox` loses focus (if you use the default `UpdateSourceTrigger`). If you want to customize the way it's parsed, you can create a custom converter to use in the binding.

Comment: About the limit enabled, it is not just a property that needs to be set, but some stuff on the UI needs to change when I check LimitChk. Or should I make a property listener to do that when LimitEnabled changes?   
   
It might not have been a good idea for me to choose Parse as the thing for the button while also talking about int32.Parse. The Parse on the button is actually some other Parse. I'll replace it with DoStuff.